# How to exclude/ignore a project(Dot Net) while configuring a Jenkins job

Tags: .net, jenkins, msbuild, build-automation, jenkins-mstest

To build the solution using **Jenkins**, the physical path of "MSBuild.exe" & ".sln" file has been configured correctly.

All the projects built successfully except MSTEST project.

The reason behind this is 'the MSTEST project needs Visual-Studio to be installed'.
Now, either I need to find a way to build the MSTEST project without installing Visual-Studio, OR I **need to exclude the MSTEST project while configuring 'Jenkins job' as it needs Visual-Studio to be installed**.

Kindly advise.

Answer (score 1):

By default your project has a Release and a Debug configuration. (See [Understanding Build Configurations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kkz9kefa.aspx)). You can add a new configuration and Call it `ReleaseNoMstest`. Copy the settings from the Release configuration, and then exclude the MsTest project. (See also [How to: Exclude Projects from a Build](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj676765.aspx)). Finally, in jenkins select the ReleaseNoMstest for building.

Comment: Thanks for your advice @wimh.. Unchecking the project in configuration-manager is NOT working for me. KIndly advise, if I need to do anything else. I followed the following steps: 1) created a release-mode as suggested and unchecked the project(MSTest) in configuration-manager. 2) then cleaned and re-built the solution. But the solution-file still contains the reference of 'MSTest' project. It works only when I exclude the project.